# Does on hold show names to all reputation levels and should it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, on-hold

Today I get a (very polite) email to my email account from someone who's question I'd voted to close. There were 2 other addressees in the email too.

It seems he'd gone through the list of "put on hold by" names, from each profile gone to the website link, used that to try and guess/find an email and then sent an email to us all asking us to review the close and see if it should be re-opened since he had edited the question.

Which is showing initiative and all but completely unneeded as his edit would have put the question in the re-open queue automatically.

So:

1. Should there be a message when you edit a closed question saying "thank you for your edit, your question will automatically be evaluated and considered for re-opening. If your question is not re-opened in the next day please read the FAQ and consider further edits"
2. Should the list of closers just say "closed by 5 users" rather than listing the names if someone under X reputation views it.

Or does either of those things already happen?

This is just a once off so far but I've only been on the site a couple of weeks so if this starts happening regularly it could become annoying :)

Comment: How did he get your email ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to respond to people who send you emails to undelete questions on StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213284/how-to-respond-to-people-who-send-you-emails-to-undelete-questions-on-stackoverf)

Comment: @qwertynl This is different in that instead of being spam designed to steal paypal information, it's a sincere attempt to get a question reopened.

Comment: Perhaps consider pointing him to this meta question.

Comment: @TravisJ There is no question. By question reopen he means the mentioned in OP's email.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname - I took it that there was a specific question mentioned in the email. So Tim could navigate to that question, and leave a link in the comments there to this meta post. However, if it was just a generic "you closed my question" without a specific reference, or if Tim cannot infer the user, then I understand how not having a question link would be an issue.

Comment: He did mention a specific question, in fact I just went back and found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727724/how-to-intercept-ssh-password-request-in-a-java-program

Comment: Ironically enough I only read the email today and it was re-opened last night. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should the list of closers just say "closed by 5 users" rather than listing the names if someone under X reputation views it.

I don't think the closing votes should be anonymous for transparency.
But the fact that they are public **doesn't** mean that we want the users to contact you.

> Should there be a message when you edit a closed question saying "thank you for your edit, your question will automatically be evaluated and considered for re-opening. If your question is not re-opened in the next day please read the FAQ and consider further edits"

This feature is already implemented in the on-hold grace period after which, the question becomes closed and an edit won't send it in the reopen queue. Pointing to the user that the post will show up to the review queue is a good idea.

---

Maybe the problem is how the user got your email address in the first place? Correct me if I'm wrong but this information is private in your account. Also, just mark him as spam it will probably never happen again. If it does, mark it as spam again, there isn't really much you can do about it. Ignore the user he will stop eventually.

Now if it wasn't for transparency, I guess we could consider hiding the names of the voters but would it really be worth it? I mean, are new users the real problem? I'm sure users with a bit of rep would still consider writing to you and we would end up with the same problem.

Comment: "Do you have any idea the amount of review work this would require?"  Yes, actually, we do, given that that feature has already been implemented (it was added right around when the term "on hold" was introduced).  The feature request is merely to display it a bit more prominently.

Comment: @Servy Every posts that are **closed** but edited once are sent to the Re-open queue ? I highly doubt that. I think it's posts that were edited and have a reopen vote already no ?

Comment: **Any** "on hold" post that is edited (by any user; at first it was just edits by the OP, but even that changed) goes to the reopen queue.  Once it has been closed edits no longer send it to the reopen queue.  That is the only functional difference between "on hold" and "close", the rest is all just how they're displayed.

Comment: @Servy Wasn't aware of that thanks. I will update my post.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Telling people that their onhold post has already been put in the review queue would mean they know there is no point in contacting people.

Comment: @TimB How did he get your email ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think he navigated to my profile, from there to my website, from there found or worked out my email. I don't want to take that down though as I get business related queries that I do want to receive through it.

Comment: @TimB I understand that. Just wondering.

Comment: This particular case is a 1 reputation new user, which is why I wondered if a filter on blocking anyone under some pretty low limit might be worthwhile. I think just letting them know about the re-open queue might be enough by itself though. :)

Comment: Should I open a separate feature request for that?

Answer (score 0):

Comment: [This is a test please do not delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213330/add-empty-answers-with-application).