# "Empty" answers will make the app crash

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

If I simply but HTML like

```
<sub></sub><sub></sub><sub></sub>
```

In the StackExchange app, I can add empty answers.

> [image]

The only check made is the 30 characters.

---

Turns out it was already possible to do it on meta. Anyways :

**Posting an empty answer like this will make the app crash**

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Werner The question in a bug report?

Comment: @Werner It's a bug report.  He's assuming you shouldn't be allowed to do this.  Meta is different in that not all questions need to actually ask a question.

Comment: You can do this with unicode as well.

Comment: You can also do this with comment markup `<! text ?>`.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, people can also just fill an answer with gibberish if they want to.  I don't see how this is any different than any other low quality answer one could write.  It should be deleted in short order with minimal fuss.

I don't see how we'd be better off forcing people to write *visible* garbage if they just want to come and post garbage.

Comment: If it's easy to block invisible garbage and (big assumption coming up) blocking invisible garbage will notable reduce the amount of garbage that needs to be dealt with, it would be a net gain. I think that the assumption is probably wrong though, it's more likely that someone intent on posting nothing would resort to posting nonsense if the system blocked their empty post.

Comment: @jball Yes.  That's essentially the point of this answer.  Someone coming here intent on posting crap will succeed.  The most you can do is change what kind of crap it is.  If it were possible for someone to post crap on accident, say my mis-clicking the "post answer" before they were done, they could post a bad answer (i.e. a blank one) unintentionally.  That's the kind of thing worth writing code for.

Answer (score 5):

If you see an empty answer in the wild just downvote, flag, and move on.

There are plenty of interesting things you can do in the text area (just look at the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)!).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to get the app to crash by posting an answer consisting of your example.

If you you have a different test case that does crash it, please post steps to recreate it on your question. For now this is a [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: Also, the first revision of the question did not mention any crashing at all. Quite a vague bug report.